# ViewData displaying database column name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, viewdata

I've tried inputting some data into a `ViewData` called "Cost". This is taking a value from the "PrinterCreditsCost" column in a database, and should display the value of that column. However, the Column name is also displayed with curly brackets, so as opposed to just display "2" it displays "{ PrinterCreditCost = 2 }". Does anyone know how can I have it so that it only displays "2". This is going to be used in a mathematical equation, so I only need the 2.

The code is as follows:

```
var result = (from a in db.tblOptions.Include(t => t.PrinterCreditCost)
where a.ID == 1
select new
{
    a.PrinterCreditCost
}
).First();
ViewData["Cost"] = result;
```

Update for Jason:

```
        public int ID { get; set; }
    public int Visible { get; set; }
    public int DeleteLicense { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ICTSurvey { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> PaidWorkSurvey { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ICTGeneralSurvey { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> PESSCLSurvey { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> PastSurvey { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> PresentSurvey { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Yr11Survey { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> NewScientistCount { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> UCASYear { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> OnlineSurveyActive { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> OnlineExaminationsActive { get; set; }
    public string UCASFirstHalf { get; set; }
    public string UCASSecondHalf { get; set; }
    public string SIMSManual { get; set; }
    public string SIMSApplication { get; set; }
    public string SIMSAmpark { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> PrinterCreditFund { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> PrinterCreditCost { get; set; }
    public string UCASIndividualFirstHalf { get; set; }
    public string UCASIndividualSecondHalf { get; set; }
    public string BookingSheetYear { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> InductionDate { get; set; }
    public string InductionYear { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<tblPrinterCredit> tblPrinterCredits { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this bit of the query

```
select new
{
    a.PrinterCreditCost
}
```

is there a property of `PrinterCreditCost` you need to use e.g.

```
select new
{
    a.PrinterCreditCost.Value
}
```

I don't know if `Value` is the property you need, it might be called something else.

As it stands, it does indeed look like your query is returning the column definition, rather than the value of that column.

EDIT:

I see the following:

`public Nullable<int> PrinterCreditCost { get; set; }`

So I'm surprised that

```
select new
{
    a.PrinterCreditCost.Value
}
```

Does not work. As it's a nullable value, the `.Value` property should return the value, not `{ Value = 2 }`. I'm not sure what's going on there.

Comment: Tried adding .Value and it gives a similar result. Rather than "PrinterCreditsCost = 2" it has "Value = 2"

Comment: Can you post the code for the class `PrinterCreditCost` please?

Comment: I'll update the question with it. A lot of it is completely redundant for this specific controller, for what it's worth. The table relates to a lot of other tables etc.

Comment: Changing it to ViewData["Cost"] = result; to ViewData["Cost"] = result.Value worked :)

Comment: Hmmm, I wasn't expecting that, but I'm glad it now works for you :)

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to store result in a string and select substring of that stored string and assign that to View data.

```
  string abc = result;
  string viewdatastring = abc.substring(20);
  ViewData[Cost]= viewdatastring
```

Just look here for tutorial on substrings

http://www.dotnetperls.com/substring

Comment: Unfortunately, it's an int and not a string so can't use strings for it.

Comment: convert int to string by using Tostring method and you can also convert back to int if required by using int.parse method. You can get plenty of examples by doing google search.

Comment: Thanks. If any solution provided by stack overflow members is useful to you, please up vote the solution if the solution works please accept the solution by clicking on tick mark nearer to the answer. Thanks again.

Comment: So, I've tried using ".ToString()" instead of .First at the end of the query, and then, just as a test, tried String sub = result; string substring = sub.SubString(4). This returns CT [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], [Extent1].[PrinterCreditCost] AS [PrinterCreditCost] FROM [dbo].[tblOptions] AS [Extent1] WHERE 1 = [Extent1].[ID]  as opposed to any of the actual result. It looks to me as though it's trying to substring the Linq query, rather than the result?

Comment: do not try ToString to the end of the query. Use ToString() only to the stored result of the query.   i.e; result.Tostring()

Comment: Did you solve this issue?.  If the answer provided by stack overflow members is useful to you, please do not forget to up vote and accept the answer. You can also down vote if you think that answer is wrong or not useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = (from a in db.tblOptions.Include(t => t.PrinterCreditCost)
where a.ID == 1
select new
{
    a.PrinterCreditCost
}
).First();
ViewData["Cost"] = result;
```

Is incorrect, however, changing it to:

```
    var result = (from a in db.tblOptions.Include(t => t.PrinterCreditCost)
where a.ID == 1
select new
{
    a.PrinterCreditCost
}
).First();
ViewData["Cost"] = result.Value;
```

(adding .Value) to the end of the ViewData line will work.